# Can we use Saucelabs with cucumber js and puppeteer project for cross browser testing?

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, puppeteer, saucelabs

We have written a test automation suite, which is using puppeteer for browser automation and cucumber for test execution.
Can we integrate saucelabs with it for cross browser testing?

Answer (score 2):

Good question, one we get a lot.

Puppeteer only supports Chrome. Sauce Labs, or any other cloud vendor, can't add extra support if the framework itself doesn't support it.

If you want to run Puppeteer tests on Sauce Labs then [this document](https://docs.saucelabs.com/web-apps/automated-testing/puppeteer/) might be useful.